# C++ - Error linking dynamic library with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, tbb

I'm relatively new to C++ and I'm getting some weird linker errors that I don't quite understand. In Visual Studio I have a project, "Engine", that builds to a .dll file. I have a macro for using __declspec(dllexport/dllimport) as follows:

```
#if _WINDLL
    #define V3API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define V3API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

All public functions inside of "Engine" are prefixed with V3API. _WINDLL is defined in the project settings and I get both a .dll file and a .lib file, and as I understand the .lib should point to the actual functions inside the .dll.

"Engine" has three libraries which are (I assume anyways) dynamically linked: Vulkan, Intel's TBB, and GLFW.

I have a second project, "Client", in which I want to use functions from the "Engine" library. I have added a reference to "Engine" from "Client" inside of Visual Studio, however when I build "Client", the linker looks for "tbb_debug.lib".

Why does "Client" need a reference to TBB? I thought the point of dynamic linking is so sub-projects of a library don't require the external libraries used by the main project. I'm obviously missing something here.

If I give "Client" a reference to tbb.lib and tbb_debug.lib, I get a linker error (LNK2019) for all functions imported from "Engine". Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction here. Here's an example of the output:

```
Client.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl EventListener
```

Comment: A small correction: The point of dynamic linking is that you don't have to replace an entire program for a change to one of the libraries. I don't have a good answer for your main problem, the unresolved external. There are too many unknowns. Check with `Dumpbin /exports` to see if you have problems with name mangling or the calling convention.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification! So I managed to get it building - I was trying to import a template class and that was throwing the linker errors. I guess I'll do more resesrch.